# EEVEE Volumetrics disappears when I plug in a noise texture to density node

Tags: volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

Been trying to get this to work. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? The volumetrics disappears when I plug in any noise to the volume scatter node. I've also tried other textures.

Thanks in advance :)

[image: Noise Texture not plugged in]

[image: Plugged in noise texture]

Comment: I've tried to replicate this with 2.80.36 (looks like you're using 2.80.35) but can't get this same behaviour - my volumetrics are shown both with and without the Voronoi attached. You could try it on the latest beta release or share your Blend so someone can check for other differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Mac. I don't know if someone already reported it, but I saw a video on Blendernation ("Blender 2.8 Eevee Volumetrics tutorial from Chocofur") and there was a comment from someone with the same problem and Chocofur confirmed it on his Mac.