# Having Issues with Volumetric Fog

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, volumetrics

how are y'all doing? I have a slight problem going on with creating volumetric fog. Here's the story:

I was following along with a tutorial from Ducky3D and he got to a part where he started showing how to do volumetric fog in the shading tab. That's where everything stop! I did the exact same thing where my fog was there and the moment I add a noise texture node, it complete disappears. I played with all the settings on the noise texture and nothing. I search and review many other videos and questions in forums about this but nothing in close comparison.

Check this out:

This is from trying with a Mix Shader node mentioned and shown from someone's answer to another question on here
[image]

Here is what happens when I add the Noise Texture connected to the ColorRamp to the Mix Shader...Gone.
[image]

This is following along with the tutorial (don't mind the other nodes, just pay attention to the connections)...still gone.
[image]

However once I disconnect the Noise texture from the ColorRamp...it reappears.
[image]

I do not know if it is something I am doing wrong or some setup settings I need to setup in Preferences but I am at a lost and I need y'all collective minds because HELP!!!!!

Comment: There is a bug (https://developer.blender.org/T85778) that relates to the rendering of emission with non-zerodensity.... I don't know whether this could be related but I'm mentioning it anyway.

Comment: @RichSedman thanks for the mention of the bug but after looking at it, my only guess is that the Principled Volume node has a bug in it or something that pretends texture nodes from functioning with it because it works fine with the ColorRamp but the moment the texture node is connected, the fog disappears which is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further digging, found the culprit...it's a bug between Blender and the iOS system for Apple computers ([EEVEE Volumetrics disappears when I plug in a noise texture to density node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125033/eevee-volumetrics-disappears-when-i-plug-in-a-noise-texture-to-density-node)) (https://developer.blender.org/T65873) One that seems hasn't been fix completely yet but currently trying some work arounds to achieve volumetric fog

UPDATE!!!
Recently received a recommendation from an account from Youtube where I asked Ducky3D about this issue. Account name, Blender Fun. The recommendation was substituting the Texture Coordinate with Geometry from the "Input" drop-down menu in the Shading Tab. You can play around with the connections but if I remember right, everything below "True Normal" makes the fog disappear. However, this is a solution to create Volumetric Fog for Blender users on Mac, iMac, and Macbook.

[image]

[image]